# ng-repeat show items for item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do ng-repeat, which shows every item, for my `n.name`, so if the name repeats itself (like in my code - there is three "asd") let show for it in `colspan="100%"` every weights.
This is my code

```
<p ng-repeat="n in messages">
    {{n.name}}
    {{n.weight}}
</p>
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th>name</th>
                          <th>weight</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat-start="n in messages ">
                        <td>{{n.name}}</td>
                       <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="n.expanded" ng-click="expand(n);">-</button></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!n.expanded" ng-click="expand(n);">+</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-if="n.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
                        <td colspan="100%" class="text">
                                    {{n.weight}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.messages = [
    {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '19'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '21'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '26'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'dsa',
    'weight' : '17'
     }
  ];
   $scope.expand = function(select) {

                    var boolexpansion = !select.expanded;

                    angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(n) {
                        n.expanded = false;
                    });
                    if(boolexpansion) {
                        select.expanded = !select.expanded;
                    }
                }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just regrouping your data in the controller before rendering it

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.messages = [
    {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '19'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '21'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '26'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'dsa',
    'weight' : '17'
     }
  ];
   $scope.expand = function(select) {

                    var boolexpansion = !select.expanded;

                    angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(n) {
                        n.expanded = false;
                    });
                    select.expanded = !select.expanded;
                }
                
                $scope.regroup = function(){

 var values = $scope.messages.reduce(function (obj, item) {
  obj[item.name] = obj[item.name] || [];
  obj[item.name].push(item.weight);
  return obj;
 }, {});

 $scope.groupedMessages = Object.keys(values).map(function (key) {
  return {name: key, weight: values[key]};
 });
};
$scope.regroup();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">


<p ng-repeat="n in messages">
    {{n.name}}
    {{n.weight}}
</p>
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th>name</th>
                          <th>weight</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat-start="n in groupedMessages ">
                        <td>{{n.name}}</td>
                       <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="n.expanded" ng-click="expand(n);">-</button></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!n.expanded" ng-click="expand(n);">+</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-if="n.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
                        <td colspan="100%" class="text">
                                    {{n.weight}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps easier to reorganize your data.

```
$scope.messages = [
    { 
        name: 'asd', 
        weights: ['19', '20', '21'] 
    }, 
    {
        name: 'dsa', 
        weights: ['17']
    }
];
```

Now you can just do a second ng-repeat on the weights.
A function to re-organize your data should not be so hard to write.
Something like:

```js
var foo = [
    {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '19'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '21'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'asd',
    'weight' : '26'
     },
      {
    'name' : 'dsa',
    'weight' : '17'
     }
  ];
  
  var tempData = {};
  
  
  foo.forEach(function(bar) {
    if(!tempData[bar.name]) {
      tempData[bar.name] = [bar.weight];
    } else {
      tempData[bar.name].push(bar.weight);
    }
  });
  
  foo = [];
  
  for(i in tempData) {
    if (tempData.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        foo.push({name: i, weights: tempData[i]})
    }
}
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I can't because i am getting data from server

Comment: @bafix2203 Of course you can re-organize your data! You can write javascript code?

Comment: @bafix2203 See the code snippet in my answer for an example on how you could re-organize your data.